# How to Load Data into remote Neo4j AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I want to import data into a Neo4j instance brought up in AWS (community edition from AWS marketplace). One option is to convert the data to CSV and run the `LOAD CSV` command in the Neo4j UI, and point it to a public http address that reads from S3. This, however, means we need to publicly expose the file externally which would expose sensitive data. How else can import this data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use any of the Neo4j driver like Python or Java. Here is one Python example that I used in my posts:

```
def store_to_neo4j(distances):
  data = [{'source': el[0], 'target': el[1], 'weight': distances[el]} for el in distances]
  with driver.session() as session:
    session.run("""
    UNWIND $data as row
    MERGE (c:Character{name:row.source})
    MERGE (t:Character{name:row.target})
    MERGE (c)-[i:INTERACTS]-(t)
    SET i.weight = coalesce(i.weight,0) + row.weight
    """, {'data': data})
```

You don't want to execute the import line by line, but you want to batch lets say 1000 rows in a parameter and then use UNWIND operator to import this data.